# plain text link into NextGen Gallery

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I have WordPress pages showing slideshows of NextGen Gallery images, for different species of insects [in fact the images are distribution maps, the thumbnails being all very similar are not helpful in determining where to start viewing].
Instead of showing thumbnails which link to the relevant spot in the gallery, I wish to link from a list of these insects directly into the gallery. This is in order to make it easier for the visitor to find a particular species which may be one of several dozen in the gallery.
I have not been able to find out how to do this easily.

- is there a WP/NGG option for this?
- any other suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Think deep linking is possible only with Plus or Pro versions .

Comment: That sounds like a great pity. The "greatest"/"best" slideshow gallery can't deeplink ? unless I pay ?